Economics of Christmas Trees and Interest Rates
True/False: If Christmas tree growers harvest and market their trees at earlier ages, one possible explanation is that interest rates have fallen.
My Intuition is that the interest rate represents what I am giving up to produce this good. Given a lower interest rate, I am giving up less than before and would be willing to wait a little longer to harvest my trees. In other words, I am waiting for the return on my trees to decrease (assuming DRTS in growth), so I am indifferent between having grown/sold my trees and investing the same amount at the interest rate.
